# Одиночный выбор (RadioButton) и ListView

Tags: getview, android, listview, java

Помогите разобраться. Как сделать возможность выбора только одной радиокнопки. Сейчас выводится список из БД, где можно натыкать кучу радиокнопок.

```
public class Adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
// ............................
// ............................

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        long id = getItemId(position);
        view.setTag(id);
        final int rowID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

        RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.RadioButton);
        radio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myClickRadio);
        radio.setTag(rowID);

        ImageView imgViewInfo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImgInfo);
        imgViewInfo.setOnClickListener(myClickButtonInfo);
        imgViewInfo.setTag(rowID);

        ImageView imgViewRating = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImgRating);
        imgViewRating.setOnClickListener(myClickButtonRating);
        imgViewRating.setTag(rowID);

        return view;
    }

    // обработчик для радио кнопок
    OnClickListener myClickRadio = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "ID" + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    };

    // обработчик для img кнопок
    OnClickListener myClickButtonInfo = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "ID" + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //  Toast.makeText(ctx, "ID"+v., Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    };

    // обработчик для img кнопок
    OnClickListener myClickButtonRating = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "ID" + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    };

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Здравствуйте. Надо, чтобы все `RadioButton` были в одном `RadioGroup`, тогда у Вас всё получится.

Comment: Я не понимаю мне нужно делать так:

<RadioGroup>

     <ListView>
               
     </ListView>

</RadioGroup>

?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter
Тут посмотри, может что то поможет.

Answer (score 1):

```
RadioGroup  radiogroup = (RadioGroup )findViewByld(R.id.radioGroup); 
RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(this); 
newRadioButton.setText("Рыжий"); 
radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton);
```

Взято [отсюда](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/radiobutton.php)